# React Cors issue in one sub-domain but not another

Tags: reactjs, api, cors

I'm making a React application, and to do API calls in development, I have a proxy set up in my package.json:

```
"proxy":"https://www.metaweather.com/api/location",
```

I'm making an api request to a weather app like so:

```
export const getLocations = async (query) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`/search/?query=${query}`)//full address is proxied in package.json
    return response.data //WORKS PERFECTLY
}
```

However, I cannot make an api request to a different url of the same domain, due to a CORS error

```
export const getWeather = async (id) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`44418`)
    return response.data //CORS PROBLEM
}
```

How can I fix this? I've been searching all day, and cannot figure out why one subdomain will work but the other won't?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the missing '/' at the start of the zip code?  Don't know what the endpoint looks like but if you've configured cors options on that `/location` route maybe it's not hitting it right.

Comment: Sadly no, it makes no difference ( I removed the slash out of desperation, just in case it was an issue). I can click on the link in the error and it takes me to the correct page, so I think the url is being formatted correctly.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you hitting this exactly: https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/

Comment: Precisely, https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/44418/

Comment: Post the cors error so we can narrow it down

Comment: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.metaweather.com/44418/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
 -- 
The fact that one url endpoint works and this one doesn't is really driving me nuts

Comment: Okay, I JUST figured it out, and have NO IDEA how this works. All I did was add a trailing slash to the function in question, in the line await axios.get(`44418/`). Taking away that slash causes a CORS. HOW

Comment: If you're new like me, get ready for a never-ending hair-pull of cors errors :) glad you got it to work!

Comment: Appreciate the help man :) I hate CORS so much  already